# NullPointerException on class variables and clear run for function variables

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, initialization

When I'm running the following, I'm getting NullPointerException

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:166)
        at com.example.amirtau.helloworld.app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.<init>(MainActivity.java:69)
```

(line 69 is mentioned on the following code)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {


    String[] data = {
            "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
            "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
            "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
            "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
            "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
            "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
            "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
    };
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

    //line 69
    ArrayAdapter<String> forecastAdapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                    weekForecast);

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(forecastAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

But when I insert :  data, weekForecast, forecastAdapter , into onCreateView function, everything works just fine.

Please help me figure out why the code behaves differently.

Comment: Have you at least debugged if any value which goes into the constructor is `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getActivity()` returns `null` if the Fragment is not yet attached to an Activity. The ArrayAdapter is being instantiated in the constructor (that's when member variables with assignments get assigned), and at that point the Fragment has not yet been attached to the Activity.

You can *declare* the ArrayAdapter and wait to instantiate it in `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated`

Answer (score 0):

I normally prefer to do something like that in onAttach(that is when the fragment has been fully attached to the view):

```
@public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
   super.onAttach(activity);

   //save an activity instance for use later
   this.mActivity = activity;

   //instantiate your array adapter and even pass values here
   .............
}
```

That ensures that by the time you reach onCreateView, you have your data ready! You also have your activity available and no longer null like in the above question.

I hope this helps.